# function not visible in function expressions, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, function, expression, visibility

I have a function expression like this :

```
var inputChecker = function(field) {
    return function() {
        if(field === '' || field === 'undefined' || field === null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

that I want to use in several different function expressions :

```
(function($) {
  if(inputChecker(x)) {}
})(jQuery);


(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```

But the problem is inputChecker is not visible in these function expressions when it's declared out of their bodies ? I don't understand why? Isn't inputChecker supposed to be global ?

Comment: If your function isn't declared in the global scope, use `window.inputChecker = ...`. If it is, then we might need more code here.

Comment: Why are you returning a function in `inputChecker`. It's hard to say but it doesn't look like this is what you want.

Comment: I guess the goal is to embed the field in the closure. This is a function factory. But here, admit idly, it seems pretty useless...

Comment: In fact, this function makes no sense : as properties are passed as values in javascript, the result can't change...

Comment: @dystroy espacially when the line `if(inputChecker(x)) {}` suggests that `inputChecker` is expected to return a boolean

Comment: @basilikum I started a CW answer. If you want to contribute, you're welcome.

Comment: @dystroy thanks. I just have a vague idea what a CW answer might be but what you wrote looks good so far. Would be nice to hear a little bit more from OP though since if he really gets an error that his function is not defined, there must be even more to it than this.

Comment: A CW answer is a collaborative answer. The author(s) make no reputation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dystroy's answer is definitely simpler. But if you want it your way...

The return value of the `inputChecker` is a function, not boolean. If you want to call the returned function, use `()` expression:

```
var fn = inputChecker(x); // gets the function
fn(); // calls the returned function
```

or shorter

```
inputChecker(x)();
```

In your code

```
(function($) {
  if(inputChecker(x)()) {
    // custom code here if x is defined
  }
})(jQuery);
```

---

Note: if you want to check if variable is not `undefined`, strip the apostrophes - undefined is constant, not string

```
if(field===undefined)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is a function factory. It doesn't return a boolean but a function able to check a property.

This kind of functions is sometimes useful but :

- you're here, in the returned function, checking the value of the property received by the factory. As this value can't change (it's embedded in the closure), the produced function holds no more information than just true or false. So it's useless.
- you're calling inputChecker(x) as if it was a boolean instead of a function.

So what you probably want is simply

```
var checkInput = function(field) {
    if(field === '' || field === 'undefined' || field === null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But if you really want to generate different checking functions, dependent on another value, you could use the function factory pattern like this:

```
var x = true;
var checkInput = (function (x) {
    if (x === true) {
        return function(field) {
            if(field === '' || field === 'undefined' || field === null){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else {
       return function(field) {
           //evaluate field differently
       }
    }
}(x));
```

Now, dependig on what `x` is, one or another function will be assigned to `checkInput`.